# get months difference between two dates javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to compare two dates and get the number of months that exist between them, for which it uses the moment library and I get something like this:

```js
var date1 = moment('2021-05-30');
var date2 = moment('2021-06-30');
var result = date2.diff(date1, 'months');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

however within my business model there will not always be exact dates like these: `'2021-05-30' to '2021-06-30'` Also in the cases that have `'2021-06-1' to '2021-06-15'` which are like `15 days` apart, I already want it to take 1 month even though there is precisely no 30 days difference, or if I have the dates `'2021-06-1' to '2021-07-15'` which are approximately 45 days, it already took me about 2 months, so how can I control that? any ideas? It does not matter if it is with moment or another library, I hope your help thank you very much

Comment: What about the interval `2021-01-01` to `2021-02-02` , ie 33 days?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass third param to diff function.

var result = date2.diff(date1, 'months', true);

This will return the result as decimal. Then you can use Math.ceil function to get the desired result.

var result = Math.ceil(date2.diff(date1, 'months', true));

Comment: But that will return `2` for an interval from `2021-01-01` to `2021-02-02`. Which may not be not intended ... `Math.round()` probably would meet the expectations better

Comment: Exactly, I would like a difference of about 15 days or 2 weeks, so that in that case I take it as one more month